# Downloading Excel file after creating using EPPlus

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, download, epplus

I am using the EPPlus library to generate an excel file which I successfully   save in a folder on the server.

How can download this file to my local machine?

This is my code

```
public void CreateExcelFirstTemplate()
{   
   var fileName = "C:\ExcelDataTest\ExcellData.xlsx";
   var file = new FileInfo(fileName);
   using (var package = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage(file))
   {
      var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Attempts");
      worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Assessment Attempts");
      worksheet.Row(1).Height = 20;

      worksheet.TabColor = Color.Gold;
      worksheet.DefaultRowHeight = 12;
      worksheet.Row(1).Height = 20;

      worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = "Employee Number";
      worksheet.Cells[1, 2].Value = "Course Code";

      var cells = worksheet.Cells["A1:J1"];
      var rowCounter = 2;
      foreach (var v in userAssessmentsData)
      {
        worksheet.Cells[rowCounter, 1].Value = v.CompanyNumber;
        worksheet.Cells[rowCounter, 2].Value = v.CourseCode;

        rowCounter++;
      }
      worksheet.Column(1).AutoFit();
      worksheet.Column(2).AutoFit();


      package.Workbook.Properties.Title = "Attempts";
      package.Save();
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to save this file on server or you just want to generate it each time that user requests a download?

Comment: I want to generate the file each time the user requests a download

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you are generating this file on each request you don't need to save it on the server:

```
public void CreateExcelFirstTemplate()
{
       var fileName = "ExcellData.xlsx";
       using (var package = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage(fileName))
       {
          var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Attempts");
          worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Assessment Attempts");
          worksheet.Row(1).Height = 20;

          worksheet.TabColor = Color.Gold;
          worksheet.DefaultRowHeight = 12;
          worksheet.Row(1).Height = 20;

          worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = "Employee Number";
          worksheet.Cells[1, 2].Value = "Course Code";

          var cells = worksheet.Cells["A1:J1"];
          var rowCounter = 2;
          foreach (var v in userAssessmentsData)
          {
            worksheet.Cells[rowCounter, 1].Value = v.CompanyNumber;
            worksheet.Cells[rowCounter, 2].Value = v.CourseCode;

            rowCounter++;
          }
          worksheet.Column(1).AutoFit();
          worksheet.Column(2).AutoFit();


          package.Workbook.Properties.Title = "Attempts";
          this.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
          this.Response.AddHeader(
                    "content-disposition",
                    string.Format("attachment;  filename={0}", "ExcellData.xlsx"));
          this.Response.BinaryWrite(package.GetAsByteArray());
      }
}
```

Comment: I am using sample code provided by you.. But I am calling this using ajax call and when I execute it, it goes in ajax error and not able to download excel file.   Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need to use ajax in order to download file. Do a regular get/post.  Because of the Content-Disposition headed that we set, browsers will know how to handle the response correctly (downloading an attachment). You can read about this header here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition

Comment: where is the "Response" declaration? you use this.Reponse but not declare

Comment: The file I download via this method is full of weird encrypted characters like `PK�UU�H��3` Any ideas why? Full description is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73399628/exported-excel-file-contains-unreadable-characters-through-net-wcf

Answer (score 11):

Instead of using `package.Save()` you can use `package.GetAsByteArray()` which will return a byte array which you can then stream using `FileResult` or `FileContentResult` from the MVC action to trigger a file download. This method will allow you to download the file without saving it to the server first.

Comment: This is the way to go, thank you for simplifying the seemingly simple!

Answer (score 2):

Here is sample action to download file. Feel free to modify it as per your requirement.

```
public FileActionResult DownloadMyFile()
{
    var filePath = "C:\ExcelDataTest\ExcellData.xlsx";
    var fileName = "ExcellData.xlsx";
    var mimeType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    return File(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open),mimeType, fileName);
}
```

Comment: `application/vnd.ms-excel` is the MIME type for `xls` files, not `xlsx`

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
excel.Workbook.Properties.Title = "Attempts";
this.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
this.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",string.Format("attachment;  filename={0}", "ExcellData.xlsx"));
this.Response.BinaryWrite(excel.GetAsByteArray());
```

For detailed blog: http://sforsuresh.in/generating-and-formatting-excelsheet-in-c-using-epplus/

Comment: where is the "Response" declaration? you use this.Reponse but not declare